# EasyTether Pro and Mac OS X (El Capitan) 10.11.1 not connecting HELP!

Tags: macos

Recently upgraded my Macbook Pro to Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and since then my easytether pro app will not connect. It just says "Waiting for connection from the host"

I reinstalled the correct driver onto my computer but still no luck.

I have a Droid Razr Maxx on android 4.1.2
I don't know if the android OS is too old to work with El Capitan OS X for my mac.

Or maybe is there an update on either the EasyTether Pro software or El Capitan OS that I just need to wait until it gets released.

I appreciate any thoughts on this issue.